# Custom value in http response with express (not in body)

Tags: node.js, http, express

**Short story:**

I wish to add a custom value to each http response with express using a middleware. I don't want it to be in my body. How to do it?

---

**Long story:**

The specific value is a string named `apiVersion`.

I wrote this middleware:

```
function apiVersionMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  res.apiVersion = "1.1";
  next();
}
```

I see the `apiVersion` field populated in my response object in my backend. However, I don't see it in my http response.

After reading some express documentation, I found: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.append. But is it a good practice to add a custom response in http headers? Should it be here or in another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized that my question was more about the use of http headers.

Found this in the documentation [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header). On the headers page, you can find this definition for response's headers:

> Response header: Headers with additional information about the response, like its location or about the server itself (name and **version** etc.).

So it perfectly fits my use case.

That led me to this solution in express documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set

```
function apiVersionMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  res.set("api-version", "1.1");
  next();
}
```

I also had to add my custom header to my exposedHeaders in cors:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    exposedHeaders: ["api-version"]
  })
);
```